# Adding child elements dynamically in React (state array)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic

I am working to build a Pokedex from JSON data in React. I am refactoring this project from one I built in jQuery, so it could be that the jQuery approach is causing me to misunderstand how to approach this problem with proper React thinking. What's tripping me up so far is how to dynamically render multiple child elements based on the JSON I pass from a the parent element (this would be jQuery `append`).

Here is my App.js code:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App background">
        <div className="content">
          <Header />
          <TilesContainer pokedexName="national"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The TilesContainer essentially receives the name of a Pokedex and makes a call to an API. The individual Pokemon names are stored in an array in the TilesContainer state (`this.state.pokemon`), as below.

```
class TilesContainer extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {pokemon: []};
    this.getPokemon = this.getPokemon.bind(this);
    this.tiles = this.tiles.bind(this);
  }

  getPokemon() {
    // set this.state.pokemon to the list
    let link = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokedex/' + this.props.pokedexName + '/';
    fetch(link)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(myJson => {
      let list = myJson['pokemon_entries'];
      list.forEach(pokemon => {
        this.state.pokemon.push(pokemon);
      })
    })
    this.tiles();
   }

  tiles() {
    if (this.state.pokemon.length > 0) {
      return (
          this.state.pokemon.map(pokemon => {
          <Tile number={pokemon.entry_number}/>
        })
      )
    }
  }

  render(){
    this.getPokemon();
    return (
      <div id="tiles-container"
           className="tiles-container">
             <h1>TilesContainer Test</h1>
             <Tile number={1} />

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default TilesContainer
```

Again, the idea is that a Pokemon tile is render for each Pokemon in the Pokedex JSON (which for now I've stored in `this.state.pokemon` - not sure if this is the best approach). I found an example here on Stack Overflow that uses an additional function (this this case `this.tiles()` to generate what I think is an array of returns with different child elements). The `<Tile number={1} />` is a hardcoded example of how the tile is called.

Currently no dynamically-rendered tiles show up when the code runs. Is this the correct approach. I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're almost there.

First off, never modify `state` directly. Use `this.setState()` instead. State in React is updated asynchronously. For your purposes, you should be able to modify `getPokemon()` like the following. I also removed the `this.tiles()` call, as it is unnecessary.

```
getPokemon() {
  // set this.state.pokemon to the list
  let link = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokedex/' + this.props.pokedexName + '/';
  fetch(link)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(myJson => {
    let list = myJson['pokemon_entries'];
    this.setState({
      pokemon: list,
    });
  })
}
```

A minor correction for `tiles()`: when using an arrow function and returning something in one line, use parentheses instead of curly braces. When you use curly braces, you have to include a return statement. With parentheses, you do not.

```
tiles() {
  if (this.state.pokemon.length > 0) {
    return (
      this.state.pokemon.map(pokemon => (
        <Tile number={pokemon.entry_number}/>
      ))
    )
  }
}
```

Next, since `tiles()` returns your dynamic tile components, it needs to be included in what you return in `render()`.

```
render(){
  return (
    <div id="tiles-container"
       className="tiles-container"
    >
      <h1>TilesContainer Test</h1>
      {this.tiles()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Lastly, I think the call to `this.getPokemon()` would make more sense in the constructor, rather than in `render()`.

I think your method of getting the json data and storing it in state is fine, by the way. In the future, you may want to look into [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) to manage your state, but it could be overkill for a really small application.

Comment: Thanks for your clear and well-written response. This is working now with the tiles being appropriately generated!

Comment: Awesome! Please mark a best answer if your problem is resolved.

Comment: Hey I just posted another question - similar problem but different implementation. Would you consider taking a look please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366354/load-data-before-rendering-child-elements-react

Answer (score 0):

so you are passing the pokedexName from the parent component which is app.js, once you get the props you can call the rest api call on the componentWillMount life cycle.

so on the render since the api call has been initiated it wont have any data thats why we are using a ternary operator to check the array once the api call get finished and we get the data we are setting the data to the pokemon array.

Since the state is updated react will automatically render a re render so the data will appear.

i hope the below code will solve the issue, please let me know :)

```js
// App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TilesContainer from './components/TileContainer/TilesContainer'




class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TilesContainer pokedexName="national" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;




// Tiles container
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class TilesContainer extends Component{
    //state 
    state ={
        pokemon: []
    }


    // life cycle methods
    componentWillMount(){
        let link = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokedex/' + this.props.pokedexName + '/';
        axios.get(link)
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                pokemon: res.data["pokemon_entries"]
            })
        })
    }


    render(){
        let style ={display:"inline"}
        return(
            <div>
                {
                    this.state.pokemon.length > 0 ? 
                        this.state.pokemon.map(pokemon => {
                            return(
                                <div key={pokemon.entry_number}>
                                    <p style={style}>{pokemon.entry_number}</p>
                                    <a href={pokemon.pokemon_species.url}>{pokemon.pokemon_species.name}</a>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })    
                    :
                        null
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TilesContainer
```