# Load data before rendering child elements React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to generate a list of selector options based on external JSON data. The code here is mostly good, except that part of it is being called before the data is loading resulting in no children being appended. I am sure there is a way to implement this but I'm not sure what that way is for my particular situation.

Here is the code:

```
class PokedexSelector extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {value: "National", pokedexes: []};

    this.generatePokedexList();

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.generatePokedexList = this.generatePokedexList.bind(this);
    this.pokedexList = this.pokedexList.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  generatePokedexList() {
    const pokedexes = [];
    fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokedex/")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(myJson => {
      let results = myJson["results"];
      results.forEach(function(pokedex) {
        let pokedexName = pokedex["name"];
        let pokedexLink = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokedex/" + pokedexName;
        let pokedexDisplayName = capitalize(pokedexName.replace('-',' '));
        pokedexes.push(
          {
            name: pokedexName,
            displayName: pokedexDisplayName,
            link: pokedexLink
          }
        );
      });
      this.state.pokedexes = pokedexes;
      console.log(this.state.pokedexes)
    })
  }

  pokedexList() {
    if (this.state.pokedexes.length > 0) {
      console.log("listing")
      return (
        this.state.pokedexes.map(pokedex => (
          <option>{pokedex.displayName}</option>
        ))
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <select id="pokedex-selector" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        {this.pokedexList()}
      </select>
    )
  }

}

export default PokedexSelector;
```

I tried using `componentDidMount()` as below, but I'm not sure how to specifically target one component for changes in this case (the `<select>` element).

```
componentDidMount() {
    {this.pokedexList()}
  }
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make your fetch calls before the `render` method is triggered, ideally in `componentDidMount` and store the response in the state. The component will re-render only when the `state` or `props` changes.

`state` should be updated via `this.setState()` method and **should not** be directly mutated using `this.state`.

In your case, since you're trying to mutate the state directly using `this.state` the component will not re-render. You should replace it with `this.setState()`.

Try this code

```
class PokedexSelector extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {value: "National", pokedexes: []};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.generatePokedexList = this.generatePokedexList.bind(this);
    this.pokedexList = this.pokedexList.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.generatePokedexList();
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  generatePokedexList() {
    const pokedexes = [];
    fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokedex/")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(myJson => {
      let results = myJson["results"];
      results.forEach(function(pokedex) {
        let pokedexName = pokedex["name"];
        let pokedexLink = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokedex/" + pokedexName;
        let pokedexDisplayName = capitalize(pokedexName.replace('-',' '));
        pokedexes.push(
          {
            name: pokedexName,
            displayName: pokedexDisplayName,
            link: pokedexLink
          }
        );
      });
      this.setState({pokedexes: pokedexes}); // use setState()
    })
  }

  pokedexList() {
    if (this.state.pokedexes.length > 0) {
      console.log("listing")
      return (
        this.state.pokedexes.map(pokedex => (
          <option>{pokedex.displayName}</option>
        ))
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <select id="pokedex-selector" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        {this.pokedexList()}
      </select>
    )
  }

}

export default PokedexSelector;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be this.setState and not `this.state.pokedexes = pokedexes`. Do not mutate state directly.

```js
   this.setState({
          pokedexes
        })
```